# feedback not setting to true

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to save a comment that depending on the email it will set the feedback to true or false and I'v
set my migration to have feedback set to false on default.

In my migration file I have

```
Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->boolean('feedback')->default('false');
});
```

and in my Post model I have

```
public function comment(?string $comment = null)
{
    if(request()->user()->email == 'admin@site.com')
    {
        $feedback = true;
    }

    $comment = $this->comments()->create([
        'user_id' => request()->user()->id,
        'comment' => $comment,
        'feedback' => $feedback
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Seems like, you forget to add `feedback` on your `Comment` Models `fillable` property

Comment: Thank you so much. I keep forgetting to add them to fillable

Comment: You are also setting the default as the string `'false'` rather than the boolean `false`. not sure if that would work reliably